# Login API for Prestashop

Tags: web-services, prestashop

I am working on a iOS Project in which I am using the prestashop API. Please let me know is there any API for login?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the PrestaShop webservices and filter with email and password like below:

```
http://localhost/api/customers/?filter[email]=pub@prestashop.com&filter[passwd]=19160794b7c0b413e80f58298a8d8200
```

You should not store the COOKIE_KEY of your store in your app, you should make a PHP page to give you the hashed password.

Comment: If i created a PHP page to get the hash, wouldn't I have to send an unhashed password over the internet? I don't know which one is more insecure - including COOKIE_KEY in app or sending unhashed password...

Comment: Actually, I heard about Prestashop don't have api for android & ios. Is it right?

Comment: Doesn't this expose every customer info if someone gets hold of the auth key, which is actually contained in your request?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly use REST API for Login & OTP details. Remaining method can use SOAP API. For prestashop doesn't have api for build mobile apps. Apphitect have readily built API for Prestashop iOS app. [Click Here](http://www.apphitect.ae/mobile-commerce-app.php)